# pass decimal column value to populate results from a table using linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a product table with 20 column. There is a column 'Width' which is decimal data type. I have been calling particular width value in web api controller to populate results. As an example,width values are like below:

Width  values
1       0.0015
2       1.0000
3       0.0063
4       1.0100
5       2.0000
6       2.0630

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetclassByWidthList(Decimal cWidth)
    {
        using (CrossReferenceTool1Entities cls1 = new CrossReferenceTool1Entities())
        {
            **var query = (from u in cls1.Products where (u.PrivateOnly == false && u.SelectionTool == true && u.ProductTypeID == 2 && (u.ProductFamilyID == 11 || u.ProductFamilyID == 12 || u.ProductFamilyID == 58 || u.ProductFamilyID == 59 || u.ProductFamilyID == 92) && **u.Width == cWidth**) select u.Class).Distinct().ToList()**;
            HttpResponseMessage res;
            res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

method is working fine. results are reflected if width value is "1.0000" OR "2.0000" but for other values of width it is not populating any result.

Please help me on above query where other decimal values with precision will populate result.

i have tried in browser to populate result:
1.
    http://localhost:55481/api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList/1  - result is poupulating

2. `http://localhost:55481/api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList/1.01 - http-404 error showing

Comment: Try `http://localhost:55481/api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList?cWidth=1.01` with `GetclassByWidthList([FromUrl] Decimal cWidth)`

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But it is loading the full data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging, your decimal data of Cwidth is being truncated, Please check

Comment: yes it is. rounding off up to two decimal after points like (e.g: '13.0100' to '13.01') but for this it is not populating result. Only for (e.g: '1.0000' to 1) this results are coming

Comment: please try http://localhost:55481/api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList?amount=1.01

Comment: its not working. full datatable is loaded. I think i have to convert it into string then pass that value as a string. If possible can you please help me on that query.

Comment: Casting will take additional overhead. rather you can update your controller method by adding attribute routing. like ... [Route("api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList/{cWidth:decimal}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetclassByWidthList(Decimal cWidth) { }. It might be helpfull for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Ehasanul for your clue. I just modified some thing and works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

As per Ehasanul's suggestion i Just modified my method with putting extra "/" last of that route path

```
[Route("**api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList/{cWidth:decimal}/**")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetclassByWidthList(decimal cWidth)
    {
        using (CrossReferenceTool1Entities cls1 = new CrossReferenceTool1Entities())
        {
            var query = (from u in cls1.Products where (u.PrivateOnly == false && u.SelectionTool == true && u.ProductTypeID == 2 && (u.ProductFamilyID == 11 || u.ProductFamilyID == 12 || u.ProductFamilyID == 58 || u.ProductFamilyID == 59 || u.ProductFamilyID == 92) && u.Width == cWidth) select u.Class).Distinct().ToList();
            HttpResponseMessage res;
            res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

call that url in my angular service http.get method with adding extra "/" in last.

```
this.getclsWidthList3 = function (cWidth) {
    var res;
    if (cWidth !== 0.0000) {
        res = $http.get("/api/KendoCascading/GetclassByWidthList"+ "/"+ cWidth+"/");
        return res;
    }
};
```

and its working great.